# Many DLLs in System namespace are included when installing library via Nuget

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# library targeting .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6

In other projects (targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1):

1. When I directly references my library project, the number of produced DLLs are reasonable.
2. However, when I publish the library to Nuget and install it in other projects, I get an additional 100+ files, and almost all of them are System.*

I wonder if this is due to me misconfigure something when publishing the library to NUGET, or because of something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. Those additional files are required at runtime to make sure your .NET Standard 1.* libraries run on .NET Framework 4.6 and higher.

You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/KnownIssues/514195-Targeting%20.NET%20Framework%204.7.1%20copies%20extra%20files%20to%20your%20bin%20directory.md).

Comment: From the link you provided, it seems like this is an issue for 4.7.1, while the consumer project in my case targets 4.6.1, wondering if this is still relevant? Also, is there any ways I can eliminate or reduced the number of these System DLLs?

Comment: While the document talks about 4.7.1. the same applies to 4.6.1. When .NET Standard 1.* was introduced, in order to support it on .NET Framework 4.6.1 you needed additional libraries to provide the features in the .NET Standard that were not implemented in .NET Framework 4.6.1.

In order to remove the need for those DDLs the best thing to do would be to target .NET Standard 2.0 and build targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2.